# How do i calculate the sum of all inputs with the same ID in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

They are dynamically created inputs using "append" method and have an id="subtotal1", id="subtotal2" and so on. How do i calculate the sum of all the inputs and display it within a div in JQuery?

Comment: `all have the same id="subtotal"` This sentence is making me uncomfortable, because id should be unique.!

Comment: that is invalid html.  all id's need to be unique

Comment: Thanks @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, im new to JQuery. Never knew that all IDs have to be unique until now. Just edited my post hehe.

Comment: that rule is nothing to do with jQuery - it's for HTML validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').text($.map($('input[id^="input"]'), function (elem, i) {
        return parseInt(elem.value, 10) || 0;
    }).reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r0340nk4/2/)

Comment: Chaning it to $("input").change(function(){ will allow it to update automatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var sum=0;

$("[id^=subtotal]").each(function(){      
 sum=sum+(parseInt(this.value,10));
});

console.log(sum);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/p9qsn9sf/)

Comment: Im sorry, but how would you display the output on the console.log to a div?

Comment: @lancey just you have to use like  $("#total").text(sum); http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/p9qsn9sf/1/